# How is digital data sent over long wires?

Tags: signal, network, networking

I want to have a mental-model for how **digital data** is sent over wires for basic networking purposes.  My current understanding is that on the transmitting side and receiving side, there are transistors that write/read a specific voltage onto the wire (hi/low), let's say 5V / 0V.  The devices write and read onto the wire at the same rate R.

While the writing device is at 5V, a signal will be transmitted along the wire at some fraction of the speed of light.  This pulse will take as long to read on the other end as it did to be written onto the wire, so effectively the length of the pulse is R*c*n (where c is speed of light and n is the number of write periods that the signal was hi).

The 3 possible ways this model could be scaled up for greater speeds are:

-add more voltage levels (instead of just 2 in hi/low)

-increase R

-add more lines

I imagine in the case of adding more voltage levels, this would be implemented by a circuit that produced a voltage that directly reflected the binary being sent.  i.e. in a 16 level system, 4 bits would be sent at once, with each bit mapping to 8V/4V/2V/1V respectively, in order to create any of 0-15 Volts.  Each cycle (1 Second / R), the circuit would update the voltage to transmit the next 4 bits.  The voltage level at any given point on the wire over time would look something like: [image: discrete voltage]

Is this the way "basic networking" works?

I am thinking of this in direct contrast to how information can be put into different frequency bands, where you might have several different frequencies that are **always** alternating hi/low, and the information is transmitted across these frequency bands by altering some aspect of each of the frequency bands in a way that can be reversed on the other end (by means of Fourier transforms) to extract the information.  I understand why this approach is **necessary** for wireless communication, but I have not been able to determine if this is also used in wires (local or wide-area).

Comment: Each of these methods is used in different scenarios.  If you want a more specific answer you’ll need to be more specific about the type of networking you’re talking about - UART, Ethernet, ADSL etc

Comment: @Frog are there formal names for each conceptual model? I've tried looking into Ethernet which uses PAM variants, but resources that I've found mostly just focus on the frequency-style communication.  I'd like to learn in detail about a modern variant of the first model that I described, if you know of a particular protocol that exemplifies this criteria well.

Comment: I’ve heard of using multiple voltage levels but as far as I know it hasn’t been used for data communications, although it is used in multi-level flash storage.  The main reason is that larger voltage swings take more time, so if you’re interested in high speed then using a small voltage swing (RS485, LVDS) is desirable.

Comment: Is the first model of what I described called baseband (where the voltage is changed for the whole frequency spectrum) whereas the second model is broadband? Just now getting this from this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-broadband-and-baseband-transmission/

Comment: @Frog, PAM (multi-level amplitude coding) has been used in Ethernet and similar systems for several years.

Comment: @Frog Most basic example of using multiple levels is your bog-standard 100Base-TX Ethernet that came out in the mid-90s. It does use a specific 3-level encoding called MLT-3, so it just is not called PAM-3.

Comment: How long is long?

Comment: You live and learn, I guess that’s why we’re here :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This pulse will take as long to read on the other end as it did to be written onto the wire, so effectively the length of the pulse is Rcn (where c is speed of light and n is the number of write periods that the signal was hi).

Because the pulse takes just as long to read as it did to write, *c* plays no role in determining the pulse width.

Furthermore, a higher data rate requires shorter pulses, not longer ones.

So the formula you want is \$T_b = 1/R\$ (\$T_b\$ being the pulse width or bit period) or \$T_b = n/R\$ for the length of a multiple-bit pulse.

> The 3 possible ways this model could be scaled up for greater speeds are:
>
> -add more voltage levels (instead of just 2 in hi/low)
>
> -increase R
>
> -add more lines
>
> Is this the way "basic networking" works?

Yes, all of these are done.

Another method is to modulate the data onto a radio subcarrier, and then various complex modulation schemes can be used, encoding the data not only in the signal amplitude, but also in the phase of the radio wave.

> I imagine in the case of adding more voltage levels, this would be implemented by a circuit that produced a voltage that directly reflected the binary being sent. i.e. in a 16 level system, 4 bits would be sent at once, with each bit mapping to 8V/4V/2V/1V respectively, in order to create any of 0-15 Volts.

This is more or less correct. For example 16-PAM (16-level pulse amplitude modulation, which is basically what you described) is used in  the 10GBASE-T standard for 10 Gb/s Ethernet transmission over twisted pair cable)

Not only power-of-2 level codes are used. For example, PAM-5 is used in 1 Gb/s Ethernet.

Also, both positive and negative voltages are typically used to improve power efficiency.

> I understand why this approach [frequency multiplexing with complex modulation] is necessary for wireless communication, but I have not been able to determine if this is also used in wires (local or wide-area).

It is used in wired systems. For example cable TV distribution. It is also widely used in fiber optic systems.

Comment: Adding wires in parallel not being used much in the netwoking is kind of incorrect. Your standard 1000Base-T Gigabit Ethernet already uses 4 lanes simultaneously in both directions.

Comment: @Justme, fair. Edited.